# Is it possible to convert jpg images to bmp?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm developing a sapui5 app so I take a picture with Cordova (camera) so I get my image in jpg but I  need to display this image in a smartforms so I need the image in bmp format. Is there a way to convert jpg->bmp with JavaScript, some function or module or something like that ?

```
var oNav = navigator.camera;
                    oNav.getPicture(this.onPhotoDataSuccess.bind(this), this.onFail, {
                        quality: 85,
                        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                        destinationType: oNav.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                        targetHeight: 100,
                        targetWidth: 80
                    });
onPhotoDataSuccess: function(imageData) {
        try {
            var arrFotos = this.arrFotos;
            var infoFoto = this.infoFoto;
            var imagen;
            // GUARDO FOTO EN ARRAY DE FOTOS
            arrFotos.forEach(function(row) {
                if ( row.id == infoFoto.id ) {
                    imagen = "data:image/jpg;base64," + imageData;
                    row.base64 = imagen;
                }
            });
        } catch(e) {
            MessageToast.show(e);
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

[Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) it's an easy to use npm packages that deals with images (it's a JS native zero dependency image processing library).

You can convert the jpg to bpm easily by doing:

```js
Jimp.read('lenna.png', (err, lenna) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  lenna.write('lenna.bmp');
});
```

You can use Promises too.